# change a certain number in the file based on file name in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have an input file named `part2.txt` with the following input of thousand of lines like

```
   46742       1   48276   48343   48199   48198
   46744       1   48343   48344   48200   48199
   46746       1   48344   48332   48201   48200
   48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
   48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
   48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
   48287  3.67678239e+01 -1.98150619e+00  1.50432492e+02
```

I have to change all the numbers which are integers in the second column to the number in the file name (`part2.txt`), so that all the integer `1` are changed to `2`, instead of 1 there could be any other integer too and it is not just 3 lines, it could be thousands of lines and it will become:

```
   46742       2   48276   48343   48199   48198
   46744       2   48343   48344   48200   48199
   46746       2   48344   48332   48201   48200
   48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
   48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
   48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
   48287  3.67678239e+01 -1.98150619e+00  1.50432492e+02
```

please note that all the columns are space delimited and that there are also some spaces to the left of the first column. I have tried to use it with `FNR` but its not that robust and request for some method with sed or awk in linux.

Comment: @Ed Morton, the output remains the same, put those useless dots, I meant that this thing continues for unknown number of lines, may be 1000 or more..  I can put it back too, but please the solution not with Gawk, I dont have it, unfortunately

Comment: @ED Morton, it was my fault as I deleted those, dots so I had to remove that too, that was demonstration that I have data with alot of lines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of `sed` and shell variables. Here are three scenarios, and each of them should do what you expect. Also, if you want to change the files in-place, then you can use `sed -i` instead of `sed`.

If you know the number of the file, then this would be work, assuming $n has the file number (for example, n=2 for part2.txt):

```
n=2; sed 's:^\(\s*[0-9]\+\s\+\)\([0-9]\+\)\(\s\):\1'"$n"'\3:' part$n.txt
```

Otherwise, if you have the filename with the .txt extension stored in $f (eg. f=part2.txt), then this should work:

```
f=part2.txt; n=$(sed 's:^\(.*[^0-9]\|\)\([0-9]\+\)\.txt:\2:' <<<"$f"); sed 's:^\(\s*[0-9]\+\s\+\)\([0-9]\+\)\(\s\):\1'"$n"'\3:' "$f"
```

The above snippet might fail if you're using sh or an older version of bash. In that case, you can try the following. It is slightly longer since it does not use $(...) and <<<.

```
f=part2.txt; n=`echo "$f" | sed 's:^\(.*[^0-9]\|\)\([0-9]\+\)\.txt:\2:'`; sed 's:^\(\s*[0-9]\+\s\+\)\([0-9]\+\)\(\s\):\1'"$n"'\3:' "$f"
```

Comment: part2.txt is already know so the number should be extracted from the file name, what you suggest is for the case when the number is being parsed, as far as I can understand it

Comment: and not just 3 lines, I may have thousand of lines and it may be to 1 , there may be any integer so a generalization is required

Comment: That's fine actually. All the above snippets will work for any number of lines. The first snippet is short since it does not actually extract the number from the file. The other two extract the number automatically -eg. 2 is extracted from part2.txt.

Comment: in the same location I have alot of other files too with the same extension of .txt, which one your code will take is not clear you never input my filename part2.txt

Comment: for solution 1 I got  sed: -e expression #1, char 36: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: for 3 it say, bash sed command not found. what kind of sed is that, I have a code sed is included there, why is this not working? can we not change every second integer occurance to n? we can input n=2; how to get all the second integral occurances changed with this n? this is the question

Comment: Looks like the formatting had got messed up since I numbered the options. Due to that, some of the code was appearing incorrectly. I have fixed the formatting now. Could you try again with one of the snippets?

Comment: the last one was perfect, since I am using shell on linux so it worked perfect for me in addition i have piped it to another filename with >> so I can see that the format is also kept and the file is intact too. I have just one more task left and then I would combine this 400 lines long shell script.. cheer and Man sieht sich zweimal. It says, everyone meets 2 times in life

Comment: can you please explain what is being in the code step wise, I want to understand it so that I can really work with it later, specially the addition of spaces, how can I see which part is responsible for which spaces?

Comment: it is actually giving an error message too,  sed: -e expression #1, char 37: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: specially when n becomes greater than 9 i.e. 10 or 11 there is a problem and the text slips to right, I want to keep the same position so that the next position is not reached!!!   so if you explain it, I can manage for my purpose !

Answer (score 2):

With gawk (for `RT`), to keep the formatting as intact as possible:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\\s+' 'NR == 1 { n = FILENAME; gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", n) } NR % 6 == 3 && int($0) == $0 { $0 = n } { printf $0 RT }' part2.txt
   46742       2   48276   48343   48199   48198
   46744       2   48343   48344   48200   48199
   46746       2   48344   48332   48201   48200
   48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
   48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
   48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
   48287  3.67678239e+01 -1.98150619e+00  1.50432492e+02
```

With `RS` as `\s+`, each field is a record, and the whitespaces that come after the record are remembered as `RT`, which we use later for printing. The code is

```
NR == 1 {                      # First record of the file:
  n = FILENAME                 # isolate the number from the file name
  gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", n) 
}
NR % 6 == 3 && int($0) == $0 { # after that: For every sixth record, if it
                               # is an integer,
  $0 = n                       # replace it with the isolated number.
                               # it is NR % 6 == 3 instead of == 2 because
                               # the file begins with whitespaces that our
                               # RS matches, so the first record is an empty
                               # one and the first row in the first column
                               # is the second record.
}
{ printf $0 RT }               # after that: print everything separated by the
                               # remembered record terminators.
```

Comment: it didnt work this way.. i have tried your command but unfortunately, there is still 1 instead of 2 in my file, I have thousands of lines in my code and that may be problem for your code

Comment: Do all those lines have six columns? That's about the only potential source of errors I see.

Comment: the lines in which I want to changed the numbers are 6 liners and only integers, then come the lines in which there are coordinates and could be real number. but I want to changed to 2 instance of the integers only, so this could make the thing simpler or?

Comment: The `int($0) == $0` test is to make sure only integers are changed, and it works for me with the input data you supplied. I could see it go haywire if there were other lines in the file that don't have six columns, but for tabular data with six columns it should work unchanged. Hmm...if the first line doesn't start with newlines, you'd have to replace `NR % 6 == 3` with `NR % 6 == 2`.

Comment: I dont have GNU awk or gawk so that may be another problem, thats why I mentioned AWK or sed only. that could be a possible chance of error too

Comment: GNU awk and gawk are the same. Anyway, I'm using GNU extensions (a regex as `RS` and the `RT` token), so I'm afraid this approach isn't going to work without gawk. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `FILENAME` by using a function:

```
awk 'function name(file) {
        gsub(/[^0-9]*/, "", file)
        return file
     }
     {digits = name(FILENAME)}
     $2 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ {$2=digits}
     1' a2
```

What I don't understand is why I cannot call the function within `BEGIN{}`, I guess because by then the filename is not available yet. The problem is that this means calling the function every time. Well, we could set a flag once calculated, but I will leave it as an exercise :)

Update: I don't know what I missed before that lead me to write the function, since this works fine:

```
awk '{digits = FILENAME; gsub(/[^0-9]*/, "", digits) } $2 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ {gsub(/\s$2\s/,digits)}1' a2.txt
```

To prevent calculating `digits` every time, youcan use the `NR==1{}` trick (credits to Wintermute's answer, +1).

#### Test

```
$ awk '{digits = FILENAME; gsub(/[^0-9]*/, "", digits) } $2 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ {gsub(/\s$2\s/,digits)}1' a2.txt
46742       1   48276   48343   48199   48198
46744       1   48343   48344   48200   48199
46746       1   48344   48332   48201   48200
465645       1   48566   48234  45201   48435
48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
48287  3.67678239e+01 -1.98150619e+00  1.50432492e+02
```

Comment: its just give an errors with this. it didnt return any thing unfortunately

Comment: @hamadhassan "It just give an errors" is too broad. What kind of errors? What is your impression about them? You have already asked a few awk questions, so you should try to get something done by yourself. Also, I do think it is possible to solve this with `sed`, but it can be a bit more complicated. `awk` should be better for this. Note, also, most of the solutions to your question require GNU awk, which you may not have.

Comment: it didnt work this way.. i have tried your command but unfortunately, there is still 1 instead of 2 in my file, I have thousands of lines in my file and that may be problem for your code. Further I want to keep the format also same, just to replace the 1 in the second column with the number in file name

Comment: the format is also completely changed and I cannot afford it because, I have to input that file to another software, also if I have the extension of .txt also the 2.txt is being printed as a result of the command in your update.

Comment: what if instead of 1 there is another number? how can I change that to the number in file name, your solution just confines to single number, can your make it generlized? applicable for all integers instead of 1? keeping the format same and without the printing of extension?

Comment: @hamadhassan Have you checked the code properly? It doesn't rely on the `1` at all, it just replaces the content of the 2nd column, no matter its value. Regarding keeping the format, I guess it is best to use another solution: if I edited mine it would end up being a copy of another one.

Comment: @fedorqui it will leave .txt on the end though as you are using `sub` and not  `gsub`

Comment: that what I mentioned too what the extension thing, around that I can get arround because, I can rename part2.txt to part2 only but with the format, I cannot get arround as the next software doesnt support the format anymore and the systems crashes, so I would request the solution which keeps the format as it is with just the replacement of a number

Comment: @fedorqui thats perfect with the format but as you can see in your result too, that integer 1 is still and it should have been replace by 2 overall till. Instead of 1 there could be anyother integer which must be replaced with the integer in the file name...

Comment: @fedorqui, just being curious, you said it would be complicated with sed, how about a 2 liner ? inwhich the first line extract the number out of the file name and the second sed -i scans the file in the next step and replaces all the second occurances of the interger with that number from the filename.. you really think that would be difficult?

Comment: @hamadhassan No, it might be even easy. So instead of having all these comments here, I recommend you to go and give a try to it.

Comment: @fedorqui, I appreciate your suggestion, the only problem is that I am an engineer and a MATLAB expert, I know some basic command in sed and wanted some suggestions. With MATLAB, I have done that too but we cannot enjoy MATLAB everywhere so LINUX is free, and for that I revert to the experts! I can get the number extracted from the name, but replacement in the 2nd occurance of integer is problematic for me, being in the learning phase.

Comment: @ferorqui, if you think that -2 would undermine my wish to learn linux, specifically sed or awk, then this is not the case. It may take a little long but I will find the solution, thats too disappointing of you saying sed would be too complicated, being MATLAB programmer I know it is not, just the matter of commands and syntax and you know my approach is quite robust, but you couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @hamadhassan You have written around 10 long comments in my answer. I already spent some time trying to find a good solution and I almost did, together with some explanations, etc. Then you are trying over and over to get me this to do further. Do not keep pushing because I won't write a `sed` solution. This is not a programming service: if you want one, go and pay someone. Or do you work in Matlab for free? The time you spent writing these comments would have being more useful trying to learn some `sed`.

Comment: @ferorqui I am not pushing, offcourse, it is your greatness that you took time to offer solution, no doubt and no question to that. This is exactly the point, I can use MATLAB everywhere so thought of using linux and nobody can learn on its own, unless we have some experts guidance and some examples and then the student tries to make a relation between what is the input and what is the output. I dont mean to offend you, but just the thing that IT didnt have Gawk installed on server due to their reasons and I am forced to use sed or awk. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    fmt = gensub(/(\s*\S+\s+)\S+/,"\\1%s","",$0)"\n"
    printf fmt, ($2~/^[0-9]+$/ ? gensub(/[^0-9]/,"","g",FILENAME) : $2)
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk part2.txt
   46742       2   48276   48343   48199   48198
   46744       2   48343   48344   48200   48199
   46746       2   48344   48332   48201   48200
   48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
   48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
   48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
   48287  3.67678239e+01 -1.98150619e+00  1.50432492e+02
```

You can do the same in any awk with match() and substr().

The above preserves input spacing by turning each input line into a formatting string, just replacing the specific field you want changed with `%s`. It would fail if the input already contained a printf formatting string like `%s` but you don't have that situation and if you did you could probably work around all issues with a simple `gsub(/%/,"%%")` as the first line to turn all `%` signs in each input line into literals.

Here's a version that will work with any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    match($0,/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/)
    fmt = substr($0,1,RLENGTH) "%s" 
    match($0,/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+/)
    fmt = fmt substr($0,RLENGTH+1) "\n"
    num = FILENAME
    gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",num)
    printf fmt, ($2~/^[0-9]+$/ ? num : $2)
}
$ 
$ awk -f tst.awk part2.txt
   46742       2   48276   48343   48199   48198
   46744       2   48343   48344   48200   48199
   46746       2   48344   48332   48201   48200
   48283  3.58077402e+01 -2.97697746e+00  1.50878647e+02
   48282  3.67231688e+01 -2.97771595e+00  1.50419488e+02
   48285  3.58558188e+01 -1.98122787e+00  1.50894850e+02
   48287  3.67678239e+01 -1.98150619e+00  1.50432492e+02
```

Comment: unfortunately, I dont have GNU awk at my machine

Comment: I added a non-gawk version. You REALLY should get GNU awk though as it's got a ton of very useful additional functionality compared to any other awk which is why everyone suggested gawk solutions.

Comment: I understood it right then, I run the scripts on the server and I must contact the IT guys and request them not to limit the functionality.. I would take your suggestion right away!